# Should Cartoon tag and Animation tag be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[cartoons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartoons) and [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) exist separately.  Is there a reason they should be separated, or would we be better off merging/synonymousing them?

I see nothing special that [cartoons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartoons) brings to the table as all cartoons can be tagged [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation), with no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO animation should be the main tag, and cartoon should become a synonym.

Comment: Got it; Completed.